# Remove site to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I try remove site to another domain. On the new domain site is located in a subfolder, and i have problem with htacces

htacces on my old domain mydomain.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|media|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

New site location is mydomain.com/site/

Links to pages and images are not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's in a subfolder you need to add the `rewritebase`. Make sure this .htaccess is also in `/site/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|media|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```